# Generate all combinations of values that are less than array's elements and have a sum = target

Tags: python, sum, subset, combinations

I want to find a way to generate sets that contain elements that sum to a certain target. Initially, I have an array that contains elements representing the maximum value that can be stored in that index.

For example, the input is [8,6,1] and the target is 10. The algorithm should produce all sets that have elements [ (<=8), (<=6), (<=1) ] such that their sum is equal to 10. Examples include: [8,1,1], [8,2,0], [7,3,0], ...

A major consideration for this algorithm is that it should work on any input length (the above example has a length of 3).

I think the solution is close to the subset sum problem, but I wasn't able to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Side note: python code is preferred, but Pseudo-code should be fine.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: @KlausD. It is not about the code. I am having some trouble finding the logic behind this. Once I understand the logic, I can write the code. Thanks though.

Comment: Here on SO it is all about your code and your participation. It is not accepted to just drop a task off without showing any effort.

Comment: If your question is truly about the algorithm and not the code, it might be a better question for the [computerscience.se] or [math.se] stack sites

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. Will keep that in mind. Sorry new here :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very naive solution for you.

```
def set_of_sums(inputs, target):
    list_of_answers = []
    for i in range(0, inputs[0] + 1):
        for j in range(0, inputs[1] + 1):
            for k in range(0, inputs[2] + 1):
                if (i + j + k) == target:
                    temp = []
                    temp.append(i)
                    temp.append(j)
                    temp.append(k)
                    list_of_answers.append((temp))
    return list_of_answers


print(set_of_sums([8,6,1] ,10))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I forgot to mention in the question, is there a way to make it work for any input's length?

Comment: You would need to adapt it into a recursive function which subtracted the first value in the for loop from the target. That is substantially more complex.